# Basis of $\mathbb C^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^3$ is $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$. Does this basis work for $\mathbb C^3$? Is there a canonical basis of $\mathbb C^3$? Does my question depend on the field of the scalars? ($\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this basis works also for $\mathbb C^3$. Reason: if $(u,v,w) \in \mathbb C^3$, then

$(u,v,w)=u*(1,0,0)+v*(0,1,0)+w*(0,0,1)$

and $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ are linear independent in $ \mathbb C^3$

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

If the scalars are complex, it's exactly the same.  But if the scalars have to be real, then $\mathbb{C}^3$ is a six dimensional space.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit why? thank you very much for your answer

Comment: What do you think would be a basis for $\mathbb{C}$ if the scalars are in $\mathbb{R}$?  [Hint: this space would be two dimensional]

Comment: I got it. Thank you again.